# How to add sys/socket and netinet/in lib in clion

Tags: c, sockets, cmake, clion

I'm trying to use socket in clion but i don't know how to add the compilation command `-lnsl` and `-lsocket` to cmake. So I'm unable to use it because it doesn't know those libraries.

Answer (score 2):

CLion uses cmake. The only way to to develop with CLion is to learn the basics of cmake. Spending this time is well worth it, because you will learn how to build C and C++ code in a cross-platform and modern way.

CLion has extensive documentation. See [Working with CMake](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.2/working-with-cmake.html) on the CLion web site.